# Is it a good practice to use both active_model_serializer and Jbuilder?

Tags: active-model-serializers, jbuilder

I have a legacy `Ruby on Rails API` project, I notice that the project uses both `active_model_serializer` and `Jbuilder`. There are `app/serializers` diretory for `active_model_serializer`, and `app/view/api/` for `Jbuilder`.

I'm new to `Ruby on Rails API`. From what I have read from the internet it seems `active_model_serializer` and `Jbuilder` are both used to deal with `JSON` data, there's even an article arguing which one is better.

I don't know which one is better, but is it a good practice to use both?

Comment: No,  it's confusing. Most projects just pick one, so it's unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem in using both, but it's definitely not a good practice. It can be confusing for new people coming to the project. I'd say it's ok to use both if you transition from one to the other (most often from Jbuilder to AMS), but it's good to eventually stick with one of them.